# Loading Files on https in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to install wordpress in a subfolder. Right now i am using the Cloudflare  SSLon my domain and eveyrthing is working fine. But in subfolderthe css and js files are not loading on https

I tried by using following  code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cashy.in/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

But i got too many redirects error.

Currently HTACCESS file is blank and my site looks like this

```
https://www.cashy.in/blog/
```

CSS is broken. How can i correct it with HTACCESS ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This should force SSL without any problems

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Adding the code given below to wop-config file

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```